# ASP.NET - What is the difference of DataSourceID and DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, datasource

What is the difference of DataSourceID and DataSource from the controls' attribute? Can I use them interchangeably?

When I try to set `DataSource` property at the design time, by typing it on the aspx page, I get an exception that says "The 'DataSource' property cannot be set declaratively.". But when I use property window to change the `DataSource`, it gives no exception.

Comment: http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/06/datasource-vs-datasourceid-internals.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`DataSource` refers to actual data source object which can be .NET provided data source controls (such as ObjectDataSource, SqlDataSource) or actual data objects such as DataTable, Collection of objects etc.

`DataSourceID` is the string identifier for .NET provided data source control and this property exists so that data-bound control and corresponding data source can be associated at the design time in markup. Internally, the control would look up for actual data source control using the id provided.

Answer (score 6):

`DataSourceID` can be assigned an ID of other data source control of type such as `ObjectDataSource` `XmlDataSource` .

Data Source Controls overview:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227679.aspx

There are various other types of data source controls as well or you can develop your own as well.

`Datasource` is used when you want to directly give the source to control such as `DataSet` or a `DataTable`

Answer (score 1):

[DataSource:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasource%28VS.80%29.aspx)   Gets or sets the object from which the data-bound control retrieves its list of data items. (Inherited from `BaseDataBoundControl`.)

[DataSourceID:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.datasourceid%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)   Gets or sets the ID of the control from which the data-bound control retrieves its list of data items. (Inherited from `DataBoundControl`.)

Secondly they can be used `interchangeably`, but you have to use carefully. e.g. If you first assign `dataSourceID` and then want to use `DataSource`, then before using `DataSource`, you have to clear the datasourceID by setting `ControlID.DataSourceID = ""`