# Does using sqldatasource with gridview work the same as setting datasource and databind() in page's init?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, sqldatasource

I have never used any of the datasource objects in my aspx pages. I set the datasource for a gridview and databind() in the page's code behind. I am looking at some samples which use a sqldatasource and datasourceid in a gridview.

My question is when a sqldatasource is used as a data source for a gridview, does the databinding happen in page's init lifecycle? Is it the same as setting the datasource and databind in init event when not using a sqldatasource?

Comment: There's a `DataBinding` event in the life-cycle, so that's when it would get bound (so no, not the same).

Answer (score 0):

1- yes , in `Prerender` event a method `EnsureDataBound()` is fired that calls gridview `Databind()` method

2- yes it is

you can check these posts :

- http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/06/datasource-vs-datasourceid-internals.html
- [ASP.NET - What is the difference of DataSourceID and DataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088017/asp-net-what-is-the-difference-of-datasourceid-and-datasource)