# use DataView when popuate a Gridview via SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I' workingon an ASP.NET project and in order to populate a GridView with datat from a SQL Server Database' table I use SQLDataSource and everythings goes just fine.

But now I need to add the option to sort the columns of the gridview(ASC-Desc), for that purpose I want to use a DataView and got the next code

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
 dv = (DataView)Ejemplo.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
 dv.Sort = "Departmento Desc";
 GridView1.DataSource = dv;
```

but got this error message:

```
Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridView1'.  Remove one definition.
```

Could you please help me and tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [datasource vs datasource Id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088017/asp-net-what-is-the-difference-of-datasourceid-and-datasource).  Looks like you want to use a datasource.  Remove the DataSourceId that you have probably set declaratively for your GridView (look at your .ascx/.aspx file)

Comment: @Tung I just did but now the gridView doesn't appears at all

Comment: Did you call Gridview1.DataBind() after you assigned the datasource?

Comment: @Tung thanks, your answer helped me out...where should I mark your anserw as the one that fixed my problem? in the arrow up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridView can be bound to a data source by either setting a datasourceId or by assigning a datasource object to the DataSource property, but not both.  This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088017/asp-net-what-is-the-difference-of-datasourceid-and-datasource).

To resolve the issue, remove the datasourceId from your .aspx/.ascx file.

@ElNeto, cheers